# LinqToSql with dates problem

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-sql, datetime

I have a simple LinqToSql query

```
from p in GL_PROJECTs
where p.CREATE_DT == new DateTime(2009,10,26)
select new p
```

Some of the records in the database have create dates with time parts other than 00:00:00, so wont be retreived by this query. What I want to achieve is a time insensitive retrieval for the whole day.

I tried the following, adding Date, in an attempt to compare like for like:

```
from p in GL_PROJECTs
where p.CREATE_DT.Date >= new DateTime(2009,10,26)
select new p
```

but in LinqPad I get the following error:

> 'System.Nullable'
>   does not contain a definition for
>   'Date' and no extension method 'Date'
>   accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.Nullable'
>   could be found (press F4 to add a
>   using directive or assembly reference)

Any ideas why this doesnt work and what I can do to make it work?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just check for the range

```
from p in GL_PROJECTs 
where p.CREATE_DT >= new DateTime(2009,10,26) && 
      p.CREATE_DT < new DateTime(2009,10,27) 
select new p
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's nullable you need to use the `Value` property first, then call `Date` on that:

```
p.CREATE_DT.Value.Date
```

That said, using the `Date` property will return the date with a timestamp of midnight, so it will still have a time associated with it. That won't be helpful for what you're describing. You can use [@AlbertEin's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2014983/linqtosql-with-dates-problem/2015008#2015008) suggestion and check for the range.

Answer (score 0):

If CREATE_DT is allowed to have the NULL value in the database it will be mapped to a `Date?` type in .net (That is the generic type `Nullable<Data>`).

You can retrieve the actual Date of a Nullable type by its Value property.

Try

```
from p in GL_PROJECTs
where p.CREATE_DT.Value.Date == new DateTime(2009,10,26)
select new p
```

But this will throw an exception if a CREATE_DT is really null. To avoid this exception you have to ensure that the Nullable type really contains a value:

```
from p in GL_PROJECTs
where p.CREATE_DT.HasValue && p.CREATE_DT.Value.Date == new DateTime(2009,10,26)
select new p
```

Comment: Actually - .Value won't throw if Create_DT is null.  You're only saying .Value to make the compiler happy.  When the query runs on the sql database, it doesn't have a .Value operation and can compare the null with 2009-10-26 (answer is 'null', which is not 'true', so the record is filtered out).